# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: Keyboard Layout does not effect some applications

Tags: 22.04, keyboard-layout, german

After the upgrading of the Tuxedo Infinity Pro14v4 from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS the German keyboard layout cannot be used in some applications like emacs GUI, Visual Code or IntelliJ.
In other applications like LibreOffice, GEdit, Terminal and even emacs non-graphical the German keyboard layout works.
Changing the keyboard layout via the top bar icon has also no effect in some applications.

Ubuntu Settings:
Input Sources: German (first) and English
Settings > Keyboard > "Use the same source for all windows" is set.

The problem seems to be user-specific. With another user it's working.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Problem solved: commands setxbmap and xmodmap do not work anymore in Wayland which is used in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

The OPs comment to the question is helpful for information but didn't resolve the problem for me. I ran into something similar and resolved it by re-adding all of my keyboard layouts from Settings: click little 3 dots beside each language layout, remove, then add again. This seemed to trigger some sort of reset such that things like VS Code now actually recognize the correct input method. Before, they were defaulting to English (US) when I wanted English (UK).

**Update:** My "solution" above temporarily fixed the keyboard layout problem, but then it resurfaced when I restarted my computer. Instead, removing all keyboard layouts except my UK one and then selecting "Switch input sources individually for each window" in Settings > Keyboard, seemed to do the trick.